# API data returned, using array to display data using JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, api

I have started a small API project and am at an impass and could use some help, please.

The connect is working fine and I can console.log(data) to return what is expected. What I want to do now is seperate the return data. An example of the data is "id":19, "code": 21, "type", zone. I have tried various ways to separate the *index* and the *element*, as I've called them, but cannot get it work. Any help would be greatly appreciate.

```
    $.ajax(connect).done(function(data) {
        $.each([data], function(index, element){
            $('#AJAXresponse').html('<ul>' + index + ' : ' + element +  '</ul>');
        });
   });
```

Comment: please provide the complete or exact string `json` that is received from the api response the parenthesis and square brackets around the `json` string make alot difference

Comment: {"id":19,"location":"005100","nlc":"0051","name":"ZONE 1*","location_type":"Zone","country":null,"crs":null,"created_at":"2017-12-13 22:32:14","updated_at":"2017-12-13 22:32:14","deleted_at":null}

Comment: First, if you print `'<ul>' + index + ' : ' + element +  '</ul>'` it wont be nice, as a `<li>` is missing...

Comment: The ID which AJAXresponse relates to, is inside a <li> tag. I can get the JSON to display in the <ul> tags, the problem is, I want more control over the data. I don't want all of it displayed and what I want displaying will be in a different order to how its received. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Try with array.sort https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems.

First don't wrap `data` in `[]`. If you pass an object to `$.each` it will iterate through all the keys and if you pass an array it will iterate the array

Then don't use `html()` in the loop as it will replace existing elements each iteration of the loop leaving you with only the last one

Finally you can't put text directly in a `<ul>` without using `<li>`

Try

```
$.ajax(connect).done(function(data) {
  var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $ul.append('<li>' + key + ' : ' + value + '</li>');
  });
  $('#AJAXresponse').html($ul);

});
```

Comment: Amazing! I spent hours researching to try and get it to work, thank you! Would I be able to improve on this and add each of the $.each to a variable so I can access them later? A bit like indexing an array so I can pick what I want displaying?

Comment: No need to add them to a variable can access each property of an object any time when you know the property name

Comment: This could land me my first Junior Dev role so again, thank you :) :)